# Getting a value error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '56,990'

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I am trying to scrap a website containing price of a laptop.However it is a srting and for comparison purposes I need to convert it to int.But on using the same I get a none type error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '56,990'

Below is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests
r  = requests.get("https://www.flipkart.com/apple-macbook-air-core-i5-5th-gen-8-gb-128-gb-ssd-mac-os-sierra-mqd32hn-a-a1466/p/itmevcpqqhf6azn3?pid=COMEVCPQBXBDFJ8C&srno=s_1_1&otracker=search&lid=LSTCOMEVCPQBXBDFJ8C5XWYJP&fm=SEARCH&iid=2899998f-8606-4b81-a303-46fd62a7882b.COMEVCPQBXBDFJ8C.SEARCH&qH=9e3635d7234e9051")

data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"lxml")
data=soup.find('div',{"class":"_1vC4OE _37U4_g"})
cost=(data.text[1:].strip())
print(int(cost))
```

PS:I used text[1:] toremove the currency character
I get error in the last line.Basically I need to get the int value of the cost.

Comment: You'll probably need to remove the separator comma before trying to parse the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The value has a comma in it. So you need to replace the comma with empty character before converting it to integer.

```
    print(int(cost.replace(',','')))
```

Answer (score 0):

python does not understand `,` group separators in integers, so you'll need to remove them.  Try:

```
cost = data.text[1:].strip().translate(None,',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than invent a new solution for every character you ***don't*** want (`strip()` function for whitespace, `[1:]` index for the currency, something else for the digit separator) consider a single solution to gather what you ***do*** want:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "\u20B956,990\n"
>>> cost = re.sub(r"\D", "", text)
>>> print(int(cost))
56990
```

The `re.sub()` replaces anything that isn't a digit with nothing.